# How to change display font in xcode 7.0.1

Tags: xcode

Typically I can change display font by taking these steps: open xcode -> preferences -> Fonts & Colors -> Choose font. 
In choosing font page, it has four tabs named: Collection, Family, Typeface and Size. In 'Collection' tab I can choose monospace font.

**My question is**: After updating to xcode 7.0.1, the *Collection* tab is disappear, so I can't choose a monospace font.

PS:*When I'm dragging the bounds to resize the window, the collection tab will appear. Once I loose the drag action then the collection tab disappear again.*

Thanks for any help, even a little hint is OK.

Comment: Although this question has a workaround, it doesn't actually solve the collection tab only appearing when you resize the screen, did you find a fix for this as I am having the same probolem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by  adding a new theme in "font & color" page, for example duplicate 'default' and name it 'hello'.
Then open folder '/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes'. You can see a file named 'hello.dvtcolortheme'.
Edit this file to change the font.